# To find the limit of three terms mean iteration

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, special-functions, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

We know that
the arithmetic-geometric mean  $AGM(a,b)$ of $a$ and $b$ defined as

$$2a_1=a+b$$
$$b^2_1=ab$$

$$2a_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}$$
$$b^2_n=a_{n-1}b_{n-1}$$

$AGM(a,b)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} b_{n}$

$$AGM(a,b)=\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{a+b}{K(\frac{a-b}{a+b})}$$

where $K(m)$ is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind:

$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 \cos^2(\theta) + b^2 \sin^2(\theta)}} \, d\theta = \int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\operatorname{AGM}(a,b)} \, d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2 \,\operatorname{AGM}(a,b)}$$

[See Landen's_transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landen%27s_transformation)

I thought If we use three terms as shown below how it can be named?

$$3a_1=a+b+c$$
$$3b^2_1=ab+ac+bc$$
$$c^3_1=abc$$

$$3a_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$$
$$3b^2_n=a_{n-1}b_{n-1}+a_{n-1}c_{n-1}+b_{n-1}c_{n-1}$$
$$c^3_n=a_{n-1}b_{n-1}c_{n-1}$$

Do they have the limit that all is equal and if yes how to find it?

$x=F(a,b,c)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} b_{n}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} c_{n} ?$

Does anybody know how to express such this kind of triple mean with known functions ?
Can we express $x$ as elliptic integrals?

Thanks for answers

EDIT:

I tested for $a=1$ ,$b=2$,$c=3$

After just 2 iterations , I got
$a_2,b_2,c_2 \approx 1.92$

Seems that the results quickly go to a limit .

Comment: This might interest you: [Victor Moll: The evaluation of integrals : A personal story](http://www.ams.org/notices/200203/fea-moll.pdf). This also talks about the relation between a class of integrals and generalized AGMs and gives a related example.

Comment: After $5$ iterations you get $1.9099262335408153237$ for $1,2,3$. Seems interesting, but I wouldn't hope for some simple closed (or integral) form

Comment: For general interest, you might check out this paper which lays out the perimeter of an ellipse, and the AGM function. http://www.math.emory.edu/~gliang7/AGM.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I find this a very nice and natural idea for generalizing the usual AGM to three or more variables, by updating the $k$-th variable as $k$-th root of the average of the terms of the $k$-th [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial), see below.

It looks that natural to me that I'd be surprised this isn't known yet, but I never saw it before. I'd suggest to call this simply AGM(a,b,c) or AGM($x_1, ..., x_m$) in the general case, i.e., call it the ***arithmetic-geometric mean of the m values***, to answer the first question, "how it can be named?"

As to the next question, yes, we can show that $(a_n),~(b_n),~(c_n)$ ***all converge to a common limit***, assuming that the initial values are nonnegative to ensure the roots are well defined:
Assume that $a\ge b\ge c$, without loss of generality because the three are symmetrically "mixed" right at the first step. Then these inequalities will be preserved after each update, and more precisely we will have
$$a_n \ge a_{n+1} \ge b_{n+1} \ge c_{n+1} \ge c_{n}$$
for all $n$, with equalities if and only if all numbers are equal. This is proved exactly like the usual [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means). (For the "intermediate terms" between the extremal cases of arithmetic mean (first variable) and geometric mean (last variable) one may apply corresponding AGM-inequalities to pairs of variables.)

From this inequality, by the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) it follows that all of the sequences $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ converge. The limits $a^*$, $b^*$, $c^*$ must also satisfy the above inequalities, and must be equal. (If $\delta:=a^* - c^*>0$, then $a_n-a_{n+1}\ge\delta/3$ by definition of the arithmetic mean, contradicting convergence.) ■

Now the most beautiful part: The above easily generalizes to an arbitrary number of $m\ge 1$ variables. To make more explicit what I said in the first phrase, for  $\mathbf x=(x_1,...,x_m)\in\mathbb R_+^m$, let $ AGM(\mathbf x) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_1^{(n)}$ (or equivalently any other index $k$), with $\mathbf x^{(0)} = \mathbf x$ and
$ x_k^{(n+1)} = \big(f_k^{\,}(\mathbf x^{(n)})\big) ^{1/k}$, $1\le k\le m$, $n\ge 0$,
where
$$ f_k^{\,}(\mathbf x)={m\choose k}^{-1}\sum_{1\le j_1<...<j_k\le m} x_{j_1}\cdots x_{j_k} $$
is the $k$-th [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in $m$ variables, normalized by the number ${m\choose k}=m!/(k!(m-k)!)$ of terms in that polynomial. For $m=1$ this gives $AGM(x)=x$, while for $m=2$ it gives the usual AGM (with $f_1(x)=(x_1+x_2)/2$ and $f_2(x)=x_1\,x_2$), and for $m=3$ it gives the sequence defined in the original post/question.