# Prove that $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n(n+1)/2} = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1 - \frac{1}{2^k})^{(-1)^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, products

Prove the following equality:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n(n+1)/2} = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} (1 - \frac{1}{2^k})^{(-1)^k}$$

Comment: See in particular [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2111803/305862)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprized that it is in Ramanujan Notebooks...

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks!

If it helps I found the one side of equation here (problem b):

https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/AMM12057.pdf



and the other side here (page 39):
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.00578.pdf

Comment: Sorry, but I don't find it on page 39...

Comment: @JeanMarie There I highlighted it https://i.imgur.com/1LfLoBw.png. It cites this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.1988.pdf which describes this constant on the last sentence of page 9